# ssh forwarding via jump server

Tags: networking, ssh-tunneling

Full disclaimer: I come from the data world and I have limited experience with Unix and Network.

- I have Mysql running on Linux 5.15.36 (say *server A*), and I have configured a jump server running Linux 5.10.102 (*server B*).
- From *Server B* to *server A*, I can connect via SSH.
- And then I have a SQL client running in a serverless environment (for simplicity let's call it *server C*) that **cannot use SSH** for authentication. It uses SQL protocol to connect and authenticate, i.e. user/password, port, server address.

Is it possible to somehow configure a tunnel through the jump server given the constraints I described, so that the SQL client on *server C* would connect to mySQL database running on *Server A*?

Answer (score 0):

The wrong answer:

````
From what you decscribe, the following setup should satisfy your needs:

 1. Configure a ssh ProxyJump to Server A via Server B
 2. Open a tunnel to Server A via Server B forwarding localhost:3306 to Server_A:3306

The configuration for the tunnel would be specified in `~/.ssh/config` like this:


```
Host ServerA
 HostName FQDN.SERVER-A
 # your user and ssh key for ssh to server A
 User <the user>
 IdentityFile <users ssh key>
 # Be sure `user` can ssh to server B from server C
 ProxyJump user@FQDN.SERVER-B
 LocalForward localhost:3306 localhost:3306

```

Then open the tunnel from ServerC with

```
ssh -N -f ServerA
```

and then try the `mysql-client` on ServerC.

If you have problems, first try `ssh ServerA` after killing the backgrounded ssh above, and see if that works.
````

The hopefully right answer:

1. Create a forwarding configuration on Server B.
2. Create a user on ServerA and ServerB with a `ssh keypair`, and enter public ssh key into `.ssh/authorized_keys` on ServerA with `ssh-copyid ..`.
3. Log in once from ServerA from ServerB to create host key entry or disable host key checking (see below).
4. Open a tunnel from Server B to Server A.
5. Connect via MySql from Server C to Server B.

1.) The forwarding configuration (here it is done as a user-config. It may also be possible through ssh-server config, but i didn't use that so far) in `/home/sshuser/.ssh/config` on ServerB would be:

```
Host ServerA
 HostName FQDN.SERVER-A
 # your user and ssh key for ssh to server A
 User <the user>
 IdentityFile <users ssh key>
 LocalForward LAN-IP-SERVER-B:3306 LAN-IP-SERVER-A:3306
 # disable host key checking
 # StrictHostKeyChecking no
```

2.) Create the ssh login user and ssh keypair on ServerB and the user on ServerA, then copy the ssh pubkey to ServerA:

```
root@ServerA $>useradd sshuser
root@ServerA $>passwd sshuser
....
root@ServerB $>useradd sshuser
root@ServerB $>sudo -i sshuser
sshuser@ServerB $>ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 2048
sshuser@ServerB $>ssh-copyid sshuser@ServerA
...
```

3.) Log in to ServerA from ServerB if *StrictHostKeyChecking* is enabled:

```
sshuser@ServerB $> ssh sshuser@ServerA
```

4.) Open the tunnel from ServerB to ServerA with

```
sshuser@serverB: $> ssh -N -f ServerA
```

5.) Then use the MySQL Client on Server C to connect to:

```
mysql://mysluser-on-server-a:password@ServerB:3306
```

You would connect with the *credentials for ServerA* to Server B and automatically get forwarded to ServerA through the ssh tunnel.

Next step would be to automate the tunnel setup from ServerB to ServerA, so you wouldn't have to do it manually as stated in step 2.

Caveats: You may need to adjust the login-permissions on the MySql ServerA to allow certain remote hosts for the user.

Comment: Thanks @gerhard d. Only thing, as I mentioned I can't use SSH on so-called Server C (like I said, it's acloud service, serverless, simple SQL client) Meaning I can't open SSH tunnel from C

Comment: Argh! Didn't get that. Sorry. Then you would need to forward the mysql-port from server B  to server A, and authenticate on server B from server C. To get that secure, you would have to use encrypted communication from server C, which is not exactly my speciality. I will think over it.

Comment: Security is not a concern, as both server B and cloud client C are in the same subnet behind a virtual firewall. Would you mind rather to elaborate this part "forward the mysql-port from server B to server A, and authenticate on server B from server C" How exactly I can authenticate C on server B?

Comment: updated the answer.